# Implicit route binding issue after upgraded from Laravel 5.2 to 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I just upgraged my Laravel project from 5.2 to 5.3 with [Shift](https://laravelshift.com/). After manually merging the files Shift couldn't merge I opened up a tab and went to my project. And it seems that route model binding doesn't work correctly.

I use a [sluggable](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable) package.

```
Route::get('team/{team}', function (App\Models\Team $team) {
    dd($team);
});
```

But when I use the code above with a slug or an id, I just get a new model instance instead of the associated model. Even if I remove the sluggable trait from the model and use a ID in the route. 404 page doesn't display when I use an id which not exists.

I'm not sure what causes the error, any ideas? Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed after adding `\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class` to middleware.

Answer (score 1):

If you run into the same issue upgrading from 5.2, then check your Kernel file against the 5.3 version:
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.3/app/Http/Kernel.php

**\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class** should be included in protected **$middlewareGroups** under **'web'**. Probably the safest option would be to copy the whole Kernel from github so you don't miss anything.